Wordpress Webhook
I will keep it short. I want to add a custom period of time in Fluent Booking WP plug-in. I managed to write the right code to do this, but when I want to add the webhook in Fluent Booking, it asks for a URL. I really don't understand how can I link the code I've wrote to the plug-in.
Can somebody guide me on how to add this custom webhook?
Below is the code.
apply_filters('fluent_booking/week_select_times_schema', [
'start' => '00:00',
'step' => '00:15',
'end' => '24:00'
]);

I've tried snippet plug-ings but none worked.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The documentation mentions that the default already is 15 minutes. The only change you made is to have users select both 0:00 and 24:00, which doesn’t seem to be a sensible thing to do.
